# Caja and JQuery

Tags: jquery, sandbox, google-caja

Suppose I use the cajoler to sanitize third party javascript and run it in a host, and regarding JQuery:

- Can the third party application include JQuery, which will be cajoled
  in the process, or,
- Does the host site expose JQuery functionality to
  the third party?

Answer (score 1):

The third-party application should reference jQuery itself. If the host page were to provide jQuery, then that copy of jQuery would have access to the host page DOM, so the third-party application would not be properly confined.